# Getting rid of redundant complex values with FullSimplify

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

## Main Problem

I have a function $f(x,y)$ such that $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. However its expression contains redundant imaginary values and I have not been able to simplify it with Mathematica. The main problem is that the function is quite lengthy, but I know it should simplify to something 'clean'.

Here is the monster:

```
f[x_, y_] := 
 72 (1/((12 I - 16 I x + 
         I Sqrt[2] (27 Sqrt[2] x - 16 Sqrt[2] x^3 - 
            3 I Sqrt[81 + 54 x^2 + 384 x^4])^(1/3) + 
         Sqrt[6] (27 Sqrt[2] x - 16 Sqrt[2] x^3 - 
            3 I Sqrt[81 + 54 x^2 + 384 x^4])^(1/3) + 
         I Sqrt[2] (27 Sqrt[2] x - 16 Sqrt[2] x^3 + 
            3 I Sqrt[81 + 54 x^2 + 384 x^4])^(1/3) - 
         Sqrt[6] (27 Sqrt[2] x - 16 Sqrt[2] x^3 + 
            3 I Sqrt[81 + 54 x^2 + 384 x^4])^(1/3) - 8 y) (-12 I + 
         16 I x - 
         2 (-1)^(1/6) Sqrt[
          2] (27 Sqrt[2] x - 16 Sqrt[2] x^3 - 
            3 I Sqrt[81 + 54 x^2 + 384 x^4])^(1/3) - 
         I Sqrt[2] (27 Sqrt[2] x - 16 Sqrt[2] x^3 + 
            3 I Sqrt[81 + 54 x^2 + 384 x^4])^(1/3) + 
         Sqrt[6] (27 Sqrt[2] x - 16 Sqrt[2] x^3 + 
            3 I Sqrt[81 + 54 x^2 + 384 x^4])^(1/3) - 
         8 y)) - (32 (Sqrt[2] x (27 - 16 x^2) + 
         3 I Sqrt[81 + 54 x^2 + 384 x^4])^(
       2/3))/((-16 (-1)^(1/6) (9 + 8 x^2) + 
         4 (-I + Sqrt[3]) (108 x - 64 x^3 + 
            6 I Sqrt[6] Sqrt[27 + 18 x^2 + 128 x^4])^(2/3) + 
         16 I (108 x - 64 x^3 + 
            6 I Sqrt[6] Sqrt[27 + 18 x^2 + 128 x^4])^(
          1/3) (3 + 4 x + 2 I y)) (-8 (I + Sqrt[3]) (9 + 8 x^2) + 
         4 (-I + Sqrt[3]) (108 x - 64 x^3 + 
            6 I Sqrt[6] Sqrt[27 + 18 x^2 + 128 x^4])^(2/3) + 
         16 (108 x - 64 x^3 + 
            6 I Sqrt[6] Sqrt[27 + 18 x^2 + 128 x^4])^(
          1/3) (3 I + 4 I x + 2 y))))
```

### Potential Reason

When I evaluate the function numerically, the imaginary part is not exactly $0$ but very close to zero. Perhaps I cannot simplify further because Mathematica consider my function $f$ to map on $\mathbb{C}$.

```
N[Im[f[0.4, 0.3]]]
(*1.64085*10^-16*)
```

Now if I plot the imaginary part:

```
Plot3D[Im[f[x, y]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> {-0.1, 0.1}]
```

[image]

### Some context

My function $f(x,y)$ represents the boundary of a region, described by $f(x,y)=1$.

```
ContourPlot[Re[f[x, y]] == 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

Ultimately, I would like to obtain a 'clean' equation for my boundary (without all these $\mathrm{i}$ terms).

I know it can be simplified further because my ContourPlot is very similar to the equation $y^2=4x^2(1-x^2)$:

```
ContourPlot[y^2 == 4 x^2 (1 - x^2), {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

Any remark or advice is always appreciated, this function $f$ has been causing me quite some trouble and I really do not know what to do now. Thanks a lot!

#### Edit: original function $f$

the function under is the raw solution of my equations. After simplifying part by part I obtained $f$.

```
rawSolution[z_]:= 2/((-2 + (2 z)/3 + 2 Conjugate[z] + (1/(
      3 2^(2/3)))(-1 - I Sqrt[3]) (-4 z^3 - 12 z Abs[z]^2 - 
         4 Conjugate[z]^2 (3 z + Conjugate[z]) + 54 Re[z] + 
         3 Sqrt[3] \[Sqrt](-54 + 9 z^2 + 48 z^4 - 
             Conjugate[
               z]^2 (9 + 96 z^2 + 
                16 Conjugate[z] (4 z + Conjugate[z])) - 
             4 z (9 + 32 z^2) Re[z]))^(
       1/3) + (I (I + Sqrt[3]) (9 + 2 z^2 + 
           2 Conjugate[z] (2 z + Conjugate[z])))/(3 (-8 z^3 - 
           24 z Abs[z]^2 - 8 Conjugate[z]^2 (3 z + Conjugate[z]) + 
           108 Re[z] + 
           6 Sqrt[3] \[Sqrt](-54 + 9 z^2 + 48 z^4 - 
               Conjugate[
                 z]^2 (9 + 96 z^2 + 
                  16 Conjugate[z] (4 z + Conjugate[z])) - 
               4 z (9 + 32 z^2) Re[z]))^(1/3))) (-2 + 
      2 z + (2 (-2)^(2/3) (9 + 2 z^2) + 4 (-2)^(2/3) Conjugate[z]^2 + 
         2^(1/3) (-1 - I Sqrt[3]) (-4 z^3 - 12 z Abs[z]^2 - 
            4 Conjugate[z]^2 (3 z + Conjugate[z]) + 54 Re[z] + 
            3 Sqrt[3] \[Sqrt](-54 + 9 z^2 + 48 z^4 - 
                Conjugate[
                  z]^2 (9 + 96 z^2 + 
                   16 Conjugate[z] (4 z + Conjugate[z])) - 
                4 z (9 + 32 z^2) Re[z]))^(2/3) + 
         4 Conjugate[
           
           z] (2 (-2)^(2/3)
              z + (-4 z^3 - 12 z Abs[z]^2 - 
              4 Conjugate[z]^2 (3 z + Conjugate[z]) + 54 Re[z] + 
              3 Sqrt[3] \[Sqrt](-54 + 9 z^2 + 48 z^4 - 
                  Conjugate[
                    z]^2 (9 + 96 z^2 + 
                    16 Conjugate[z] (4 z + Conjugate[z])) - 
                  4 z (9 + 32 z^2) Re[z]))^(1/3)))/(6 (8 z^3 + 
           54 Re[z] - 
           4 (3 z Conjugate[z]^2 + Conjugate[z]^3 + 6 z^2 Re[z]) + 
           3 Sqrt[3] \[Sqrt](-54 + 9 z^2 + 48 z^4 - 
               Conjugate[
                 z]^2 (9 + 96 z^2 + 
                  16 Conjugate[z] (4 z + Conjugate[z])) - 
               4 z (9 + 32 z^2) Re[z]))^(1/3)))) + 
 2/((2 + (2 z)/3 + 2 Conjugate[z] + (1/(
      3 2^(2/3)))(-1 - I Sqrt[3]) (-4 z^3 - 12 z Abs[z]^2 - 
         4 Conjugate[z]^2 (3 z + Conjugate[z]) + 54 Re[z] + 
         3 Sqrt[3] \[Sqrt](-54 + 9 z^2 + 48 z^4 - 
             Conjugate[
               z]^2 (9 + 96 z^2 + 
                16 Conjugate[z] (4 z + Conjugate[z])) - 
             4 z (9 + 32 z^2) Re[z]))^(
       1/3) + (I (I + Sqrt[3]) (9 + 2 z^2 + 
           2 Conjugate[z] (2 z + Conjugate[z])))/(3 (-8 z^3 - 
           24 z Abs[z]^2 - 8 Conjugate[z]^2 (3 z + Conjugate[z]) + 
           108 Re[z] + 
           
           6 Sqrt[3] \[Sqrt](-54 + 9 z^2 + 48 z^4 - 
               Conjugate[
                 z]^2 (9 + 96 z^2 + 
                  16 Conjugate[z] (4 z + Conjugate[z])) - 
               4 z (9 + 32 z^2) Re[z]))^(1/3))) (2 + 
      2 z + (2 (-2)^(2/3) (9 + 2 z^2) + 4 (-2)^(2/3) Conjugate[z]^2 + 
         2^(1/3) (-1 - I Sqrt[3]) (-4 z^3 - 12 z Abs[z]^2 - 
            4 Conjugate[z]^2 (3 z + Conjugate[z]) + 54 Re[z] + 
            3 Sqrt[3] \[Sqrt](-54 + 9 z^2 + 48 z^4 - 
                Conjugate[
                  z]^2 (9 + 96 z^2 + 
                   16 Conjugate[z] (4 z + Conjugate[z])) - 
                4 z (9 + 32 z^2) Re[z]))^(2/3) + 
         4 Conjugate[
           z] (2 (-2)^(2/3)
              z + (-4 z^3 - 12 z Abs[z]^2 - 
              4 Conjugate[z]^2 (3 z + Conjugate[z]) + 54 Re[z] + 
              3 Sqrt[3] \[Sqrt](-54 + 9 z^2 + 48 z^4 - 
                  Conjugate[
                    z]^2 (9 + 96 z^2 + 
                    16 Conjugate[z] (4 z + Conjugate[z])) - 
                  4 z (9 + 32 z^2) Re[z]))^(1/3)))/(6 (8 z^3 + 
           54 Re[z] - 
           4 (3 z Conjugate[z]^2 + Conjugate[z]^3 + 6 z^2 Re[z]) + 
           3 Sqrt[3] \[Sqrt](-54 + 9 z^2 + 48 z^4 - 
               Conjugate[
                 z]^2 (9 + 96 z^2 + 
                  16 Conjugate[z] (4 z + Conjugate[z])) - 
               4 z (9 + 32 z^2) Re[z]))^(1/3))))
```

Comment: Is `f` the result of calling `Reduce` on a simpler algebraic expression? If so could you post it?

Comment: `f` is the result of `FullSimplifying` the raw solution of my equations, which involved matrices with complex values. I did not apply it in one go, I isolated and separately simplified parts of the solution. Merging everything together gave me my function $f(x,y)$. I can still post the raw solution if you are interested in having a look. However it is even longer than my expression for $f(x,y)$

Comment: You can use option setting such as `Cubics->False` in `Solve` or `Reduce`.